# iOS - Creating UIScrollView programatically, direct assignment vs property

Tags: ios, properties, uiscrollview, instance-variables

From Apples [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH101-SW11) they create a UIScrollView in `- (void)loadView` like this:

```
- (void)loadView {
    CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,758);

    // do any further configuration to the scroll view
    // add a view, or views, as a subview of the scroll view.

    // release scrollView as self.view retains it
    self.view=scrollView;
    [scrollView release];
}
```

So I take for granted that the scrollView var is an instance variable declared in the .h file? Why is it that they set the the `scrollView` var with a direct assignment? Shouldn't you use proper memory management (as with a synthesized property)?

The reason I'm wondering is beacuse I'm myself am creating a `UIScrollView` in `- (void)loadView`. I have declared a UIScrollView property to get a handle to the ScrollView through my class. Right now it looks like this (and is working) but I'm wondering if my code is correct, I don't like the direct assignment call:

```
- (void)loadView {

    // Setup Scroll View
    // scrollView is a property setup as (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;

    // Wouldn't it be better if used self.ScrollView instead?
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];
    [scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:NO]; 

    self.view = scrollView;

}
```

Comment: Generally I like to keep my ivars retained until `-dealloc` gets called.  In this case both methods work since the `view` property retains the object that is assigned to it.

Comment: What about using the direct assignment call to the `scrollView`?

Comment: In this case I would do something like `self.scrollView = ...`, then release it at the end of the `-loadView` method.  Then, in `-dealloc`, write `self.scrollView = nil` to free it.  I will point out that that is equivalent to assigning it directly as you are doing already, and then not releasing it at the end of the method and only in `-dealloc`.

Comment: So you can say that it's "alright" to do a direct assignment in the `- (void)loadView` to an instance variable. But in most other cases you would rather do assignments to instance variables through properties or own made setters?

Answer (score 1):

But, the memory is managed here--`scrollView` doesn't need to be retained, as it is retained by `self.view`.

If you need to retain a reference to `scrollView` then you do need to retain/release it.  However, if your purposes don't require keeping a reference around, just assign it to `self.view`, release it, and move on with your life!

Comment: What about using the direct assignment call to the `scrollView`?

Comment: I'm not sure what troubles you about the direct assignment.  You're `alloc/init`ing and `release`ing right here.  Memory management done!  Again, if you need to keep a reference around, sure, synthesize a property and clean up in `- (void)dealloc`.  There are no problems with either approach--just depends on what you need to do.